# Procura numero em texto Python

Tags: python

Desenvolvi um código python para buscar numero dentro de um arquivo excel, onde o mesmo tem aproximadamente uns 40 mil dados. Fiz uma regra para me trazer somente numero de 9 a 14, onde eu iria classificar ele como telefone. Porem alem de ter esses dados de telefone outros numeros relacionado a nota que tem 9 números.. Então ele me traz muita coisas de nota e os telefone não. No texto tem tipo tel(19).... telefone(19).... Poderia me dar uma sugestão de como eu posso fazer para ele ler a `string` e encontra tipo `tel` e a partir desse ponto ele grava somente o numero.

```
import pandas as pd

import re

df = pd.read_excel('log1.xlsx')

df['CONTEM TELEFONE']=""

df['telefone']=""


for i in range(len(df)):

    print( i)


    t=(str (df['Observação'][i]).split(" "))

    contador =0

    contador4 =0

    while (contador <len(t)):


      if(len (t [contador])>=9 and len (t [contador])<=14):

       #print (str(t[contador]).replace("-","").replace("(","").replace(")","").replace(",",""))"

              entrada = (str(t[contador]).replace("-","").replace("(","").replace(")","").replace(",","").replace(".",""))

      contador3 = 0

      confere = 0

    while (contador3 < len(entrada)):

             if entrada[contador3:contador3+1].isdigit() == True:

                   confere = confere + 1

                   contador3 = contador3 + 1

                   if confere == len(entrada):

                      df['CONTEM TELEFONE'][i]= "sim"

                      if confere != len(entrada):

                         df['CONTEM TELEFONE'][i] ="não"

                         contador4 = contador4+1

                         if confere == len(entrada):

                          df['CONTEM TELEFONE'][i]= "sim"

                          if contador4>1:

                           df['telefone'][i] = df['telefone'][i]+";"+entrada 

                          else:

                           df['telefone'][i] = entrada 

    contador=contador +1
```

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a que melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/101).

Comment: Perfeito,irei estudar melhor a plataformar antes de fazer outra pergunta :D